# Replace all elements in list Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, replace

I have this example code, I want to replace every string in "m" by another string where string modulo 10 is equal to 0. So for example in my code I want new list: `m = ['0001100001000110100000011011110001101010000010000000011100000001100101', '00011100000001101111']`
Where is mistake in my code?

```
m = ['1100001000110100000011011110001101010000010000000011100000001100101', '11100000001101111']
for i in m:
        if len(i) % 10 != 0:
             i = ((10 - len(i) % 10) * "0" + i)
             m[i] = i
u = ''.join(chr(int(m[i*10:i*10+10],2)) for i in range(len(m)//10))
print("u= ", u)
```

Comment: Simply executing the code will give you the error why posting here?`m[i] = i` is the error.

Comment: you use `i` too many times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have included the error message in your code, because it should be fairly obvious from the error message:

```
>>> m[i] = i
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

when you do `for i in m:` you're iterating over the elements of `m`, not the indices of `m`. You seem to realize this for most of the way, but I think your naming scheme (`i` is often an index) threw you off.

You can use `enumerate` to get a tuple of `(index, value)` from an iterable:

```
for i, v in enumerate(m):
    if len(v) % 10 != 0:
         v = ((10 - len(v) % 10) * "0" + v)
         m[i] = v
# etc.
```

---

If there's error in the logic of your code this may still fail, but that's the syntactical error!

Comment: Just a little mistake, v = ((10 - len(v) % 10) * "0" + v) Thank you very much.